# Simplest way to perform one-shot network tasks without using deprecated classes

Tags: android, kotlin, networking

For my Android application, I have to send an email to a specific address, with a specific subject and body. Then I have to go on with the app if the mail was sent correctly, or exit otherwise. I already have a class that does that, however I know that I cannot put the call to the sendMail() method in the main UI thread or it will throw an exception.

My question is: what's the simplest way to do that? I've already looked for a solution here on StackOverflow, but I only found solutions which use deprecated classes (AsyncTask, IntentService). Since it is a one-shot task, it seems to me that using a Service is too much.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve concurrency in `Android`, everything comes down to delegating heavy/IO work to worker thread. UI thread should not be blocked at any case as it handles layouts and clicks.

`AsyncTask` is one such way to offload work to separate thread. The reason it is deprecated is because it would not restrict developer to write better code and hence provides chances for memory leaks and does not handle cancellations well!

There are multiple libraries/ways which you could use

1. [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html), which provide a much better way to handle single shot queries by delegating it to dispatcher of your choice

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
  sendEmail()
}
```

2. [Rxjava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava), a library for composing asynchronous and event-based programs by using observable sequences.